# Scheduling a report that contains a value prompt with dates

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-11

I have a Cognos report, which contains a prompt page with a Date Valid prompt. This is a value prompt, not a date prompt.

I need to schedule this report so when the schedule is suppose to run, the last day of the previous month from this prompt will be automatically selected.

Right know if I create a schedule and define my prompt values, I select the last day of the previous month. But then the scheduled report always runs with this date which has been set, even when i schedule it to run next month.

I would like the report to automatically selected the last day of the previous month from this value prompt when the report is scheduled (for example I schedule this report to run next month Monday in September and I need it to select 31st of August automatically).

The solution found online includes macro prompt, or creating two values/options for the date prompt - one for scheduling (which will automatically select last available date according to the schedule date) and one for ad-hoc report run (select your desired date from the prompt).

Any help how/where to use the macro prompt would be much apreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Could you use a function like Current_Date, for example a filter like [Invoice Date] = Current_Date.  This way, when the report runs, it would be the same as entering the date

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  When I look at a date prompt, the last available date appears to be December 31, 9999 (because it will only use the first 4 digits of the year).  Are you actually using a value prompt that contains values that look like dates?

Comment: You tagged both `cognos-10` and `cognos-11`.  Which is it?
  DQM or CQM?

Comment: VAI Jason: thank you, where exactly would i put this function?

Comment: dougp: i am using a date prompt. By the last available date i mean that when i schedule this report to run on 1st of december, the Date Valid value will be automatically selected as 1st of december or 30th of november.
When i am setting the prompt values now, i select the todays date 8th of september, but then when i schedule this report to run on the 1st of december, it will still run with the 8th of september selected.

I just would like to select all prompt values that i need, but not to worry about the date prompt.

Using Cognos 11.2.2

Comment: Which one?  If it runs on Dec 1, do you want the date to be Dec 1, Nov 30, the previous day, the end of the previous month, the end of the previous week, the previous work day, ...?  Lots of options here.  You need to pick one.  Please define "last available date" in the context of the report.

Comment: Thank you dougp. The date prompt right now only shows the last day of each month. So when i schedule this report to run 1st of december, i want the 31st of november to be automatically selected.

Comment: try something like this: _add_days(current_date,-1)
If you ran on Dec 1st, it would use Nov 31st

Comment: Thank yo VAI Jason, where do i put that script?

Comment: Hello, could anyone point me in the right direction please?

Recap:
- the package used for this report is DQM

Comment: The prompt with the dates is a Value Prompt.
In the Date Valid query used for this prompt, i added following filter, this only displays the last available day of the previous month

[Date Valid] = _last_of_month(_add_months(current_date,-1))

When i run this report now, the Value Prompt only display last day of the previous month - 31st of August, which is a good start.
But in order to run the report, i still have to click on this value, otherwise the report runs, but doesn't display any data, just empty crosstabs, which makes sense.

Comment: How could i make this value default? With  my filter, there is only one value - the last day of the previous month.

I checked the IBM documentation, but I dont understand it

Any help will be greatly appreciated
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Step 1) On your main report query create a data item (go to the query, to the tool box and drag query calculation over to you data items)

Name it something like, **Target Date**

and the expression should be:

```
add_days(current_date,-1)
```

Step 2) Add another value prompt with static values of Y and N, name the parameter something like **ScheduleDate**

Step 3) Change the value prompt for your date, set usage **optional**

Step 4) For your existing filter based on your existing value prompt
i.e.

```
[Invoice Date] = ?SomeDate?
```

Change this filter for your main report query to

```
(?ScheduleDate? = 'N' and [Invoice Date] = ?SomeDate?) OR
(?ScheduleDate? = 'Y' and [Invoice Date] = [Target Date])
```

If you ran on Dec 1st, it would use Nov 31st

Comment: Much appreciated VAI Jason. 
I did as you wrote, although one thing is not clear for me: do i still use the first, original prompt? Or use it with a conjunction with the new prompt? 
Thank you very much again

Comment: use it with the other prompt.   The OR part on the filter expression would handle if you want to use the target date or not (for example, when scheduling your report you would select Y).  Let me know if this works for you

Comment: Following up, how is it going?

Comment: Hello VAI Jason, unfortunately it didn't work, although that may be because the report is created. Unless i select any date from that value prompt with dates, the CONFIRM button on the prompt page wont light up, therefore i can't schedule or run this report until i select the date. 
Even with your proposed solution, the last available date still hasn't been automatically selected.

Comment: Test this please.  If you select to use ?ScheduleDate? = 'Y'  
AND go ahead and pick a date so you can hit the confirm button.  However, you probably notice when testing, that it uses the current date -1.  Give it a try, it sounds like you are very close

Comment: I tried and it still doesnt select the value in the date prompt. Maybe my request should be:
How to automatically select the top value in the value prompt on the report page when i run the report? Even this seems to be not as easy as it seems, as i found this is only achievable by using java script.

Comment: Can you post the report from the clipboard, or what you have as the filter expression?

Comment: Apologies for a late reply, the developer team will eventually deal with this and add a "current month" parameter value in the date valid prompt. That way, when scheduling, a user will simply select "current month" and set the schedule date as they wish.

Comment: Many thanks again for your input, im going to test your solution on my private reports. Much appreciated.